# my query about why am I not getting desired output in some parts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator

I am not being able to get an alert response from some buttons in as an alert. I tried a lot to detect the problem but can't find it.
please help me understand the problem in the code. the AC button, EQUALS button and the button with the text "11" is not giving a response like other operators and numbers like I am trying to make

```js
function submit() {
  var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
  alert("hello");
  alert(a);
  switch (b) {
    case '+':
      a = parseInt(a);
      c = parseInt(c)
      console.log(`${a+c}`)
      break;
    case '-':
      console.log(`${a-c}`)
      break;
    case '*':
      console.log(`${a*c}`)
      break;
    case '/':
      console.log(`${a/c}`);
      break;
    default:
      return
  }

}

function a() {

  alert("v")
}
const ans = answer => {
  answer.innerText = submit()
}
const answer = document.querySelector('[data-ans]')







class calculate {
  constructor(first_num, second_one) {
    this.first_num = first_num;
    this.second_one = second_one;
  }
  text() /* this region is for output value*/ {

  }
  numbermagic() /*this is where numbers do magic*/ {

  }
  clear() /*this region is for clear button*/ {

  }
  delete() /*this region is for delete button*/ {

  }
  operator() /*this region is for operators*/ {

  }
  calculation() /*this is where the magic happens*/ {}
  display(d) /*this is what you see*/ {
    alert("you pressed  " + d);
  }
}
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]'); /*NUMBERS are a string */
const operators = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operand]'); //this loooks for operator
const first_num = document.querySelector(['data-first-input']); //this does first disp segment
const second_one = document.querySelector(['data-second-input']); //this does seci=ond disp
const ac = document.querySelectorAll(['data-a']);
const deleteButton = document.querySelectorAll(['data-d']);
const equal = document.querySelectorAll(['data-e']);
const calculator = new calculate(first_num, second_one);
numbers.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.display(button.innerText)
  })
})
operators.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.operator()
    calculator.display(button.innerText)
  })
})


deleteButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
  calculator.delete()
  calculator.dsplay(button.innerText)
})


equal.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.compute()
    calculator.display(button.innerText)
  })
})
ac.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.display(button.innerText)
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, lightskyblue, #d6ff09);
}

input {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: calc(var9(a));
}

input.sign {
  width: 2em;
}

div.calculator {
  scale: 1;
}

button {
  background-color: aqua;
  cursor: crosshair;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: hidden;
  border-width: 4em;
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 4px red);
  animation: background-color 3s;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px red);
  background-color: cyan;
}

button:active {
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px red);
  background-color: cyan;
}

button.span-2 {
  width: 140px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

button.first_input {
  background-color: rgba(000, 000, 000, .2);
  cursor: hidden;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: hidden;
  width: 180px;
  border-width: 0em;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: none;
  animation: none;
}

button.second_input {
  padding: 0px;
  height: auto;
  text-decoration-color: black;
  background-color: rgba(000, 000, 000, .1);
  cursor: hidden;
  border-radius: 0px;
  resize: vertical, 2;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 180px;
  border-width: 0em;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: none;
  animation: none;
}

div.display {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  right: 0%;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 44px;
}

span.first_input {
  height: 40px;
  min-height: 70px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  width: 280px;
}

span.second_input {
  height: 40px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  width: 280px;
}

button {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="number" placeholder="number" id="a">

  <input type="text" id="b" class="sign" placeholder="+ ,_ ,* ,/">
  <input type="number" id="c" placeholder="second number">
  <button onclick="submit()" value="submit">equals</button>
</div>
<hr color=b lue></hr>
<hr color=blue></hr>
<div style="height:30px; width:100%"></div>
<div class="calculator">
  <form align="center">
    <div align="center" class="display">
      <span align="center" data-first class="first_input">123 +</span>
      <span align="center" data-second class="second_input">123</span>
    </div>
    <button data-a class="span-2">AC </button>
    <button data-d>11</button>
    <button data-operand>*</button><br>
    <button data-number>1</button>
    <button data-number>2</button>
    <button data-number>3</button>
    <button data-operand>+</button><br>
    <button data-number>4</button>
    <button data-number>5</button>
    <button data-number>6</button>
    <button data-operand>-</button><br>
    <button data-number>7</button>
    <button data-number>8</button>
    <button data-number>9</button>
    <button data-operand>/</button><br>
    <button data-number>.</button>
    <button data-number>0</button>
    <button data-e class="span-2">=</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. After that edit your question to meet those guidelines and include your code in form of a [repro]. Pay extra attention to the word **minimal**. Last but not least, provide more details and clarity. `something is not working` is neither a question nor helpful info. What does not work as intended? what are the desired results and the received output? where are you stuck? What error messages do you get?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, the AC button EQUALS  button and  the button with text "11" is not giving response like other operators and numbers like I am trying to make

Comment: PS: `<hr>` is an empty tag (replaced element) such as `<br>` or `<input>` . It has no closing tag and as such `</hr>` is invalid as it does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to [`document.querySelectorAll()` should be a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#parameters) (emphasis mine):

> #### Parameters
>
> `selectors`
> A **string** containing one or more selectors to match against.

Whereas for these method calls, you have used arrays. I suspect that you meant to have the square brackets inside the string to select `data-` attributes. So for your method calls, they should be changed like the following:

```js
const first_num = document.querySelector(['data-first-input']); //this does first disp segment
const second_one = document.querySelector(['data-second-input']); //this does seci=ond disp
const ac = document.querySelectorAll(['data-a']);
const deleteButton = document.querySelectorAll(['data-d']);
const equal = document.querySelectorAll(['data-e']);
```

to

```js
const first_num = document.querySelector('[data-first-input]'); //this does first disp segment
const second_one = document.querySelector('[data-second-input]'); //this does seci=ond disp
const ac = document.querySelectorAll('[data-a]');
const deleteButton = document.querySelectorAll('[data-d]');
const equal = document.querySelectorAll('[data-e]');
```

Furthermore, [`document.querySelectorAll()` returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#return_value)

> A non-live NodeList containing one Element object for each element that matches at least one of the specified selectors […]"

But you tried to call `addEventListener()` method on `deleteButton` which would be a `NodeList`:

```js
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
  calculator.delete()
  calculator.dsplay(button.innerText)
})
```

You can either use the `forEach` method like you did for the other `document.querySelectorAll()` calls:

```js
deleteButton.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', button => {
    calculator.delete()
    calculator.dsplay(button.innerText)
  });
});
```

or use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which returns

> An Element object representing the first element in the document that matches the specified set of CSS selectors

```js
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-d]');

// …

deleteButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
  calculator.delete()
  calculator.dsplay(button.innerText)
})
```

```js
function submit() {
  var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
  alert("hello");
  alert(a);
  switch (b) {
    case '+':
      a = parseInt(a);
      c = parseInt(c)
      console.log(`${a+c}`)
      break;
    case '-':
      console.log(`${a-c}`)
      break;
    case '*':
      console.log(`${a*c}`)
      break;
    case '/':
      console.log(`${a/c}`);
      break;
    default:
      return
  }

}

function a() {

  alert("v")
}
const ans = answer => {
  answer.innerText = submit()
}
const answer = document.querySelector('[data-ans]')







class calculate {
  constructor(first_num, second_one) {
    this.first_num = first_num;
    this.second_one = second_one;
  }
  text() /* this region is for output value*/ {

  }
  numbermagic() /*this is where numbers do magic*/ {

  }
  clear() /*this region is for clear button*/ {

  }
  delete() /*this region is for delete button*/ {

  }
  operator() /*this region is for operators*/ {

  }
  calculation() /*this is where the magic happens*/ {}
  display(d) /*this is what you see*/ {
    alert("you pressed  " + d);
  }
}
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]'); /*NUMBERS are a string */
const operators = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operand]'); //this loooks for operator
const first_num = document.querySelector('[data-first-input]'); //this does first disp segment
const second_one = document.querySelector('[data-second-input]'); //this does seci=ond disp
const ac = document.querySelectorAll('[data-a]');
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-d]');
const equal = document.querySelectorAll('[data-e]');
const calculator = new calculate(first_num, second_one);
numbers.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.display(button.innerText)
  })
})
operators.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.operator()
    calculator.display(button.innerText)
  })
})


deleteButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
  calculator.delete()
  calculator.dsplay(button.innerText)
})


equal.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.compute()
    calculator.display(button.innerText)
  })
})
ac.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.display(button.innerText)
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, lightskyblue, #d6ff09);
}

input {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: calc(var9(a));
}

input.sign {
  width: 2em;
}

div.calculator {
  scale: 1;
}

button {
  background-color: aqua;
  cursor: crosshair;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: hidden;
  border-width: 4em;
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 4px red);
  animation: background-color 3s;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px red);
  background-color: cyan;
}

button:active {
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px red);
  background-color: cyan;
}

button.span-2 {
  width: 140px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

button.first_input {
  background-color: rgba(000, 000, 000, .2);
  cursor: hidden;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: hidden;
  width: 180px;
  border-width: 0em;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: none;
  animation: none;
}

button.second_input {
  padding: 0px;
  height: auto;
  text-decoration-color: black;
  background-color: rgba(000, 000, 000, .1);
  cursor: hidden;
  border-radius: 0px;
  resize: vertical, 2;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 180px;
  border-width: 0em;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: none;
  animation: none;
}

div.display {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  right: 0%;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 44px;
}

span.first_input {
  height: 40px;
  min-height: 70px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  width: 280px;
}

span.second_input {
  height: 40px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  width: 280px;
}

button {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="number" placeholder="number" id="a">

  <input type="text" id="b" class="sign" placeholder="+ ,_ ,* ,/">
  <input type="number" id="c" placeholder="second number">
  <button onclick="submit()" value="submit">equals</button>
</div>
<hr color=b lue></hr>
<hr color=blue></hr>
<div style="height:30px; width:100%"></div>
<div class="calculator">
  <form align="center">
    <div align="center" class="display">
      <span align="center" data-first class="first_input">123 +</span>
      <span align="center" data-second class="second_input">123</span>
    </div>
    <button data-a class="span-2">AC </button>
    <button data-d>11</button>
    <button data-operand>*</button><br>
    <button data-number>1</button>
    <button data-number>2</button>
    <button data-number>3</button>
    <button data-operand>+</button><br>
    <button data-number>4</button>
    <button data-number>5</button>
    <button data-number>6</button>
    <button data-operand>-</button><br>
    <button data-number>7</button>
    <button data-number>8</button>
    <button data-number>9</button>
    <button data-operand>/</button><br>
    <button data-number>.</button>
    <button data-number>0</button>
    <button data-e class="span-2">=</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

There are some other typos and such in the snippet but this should be sufficient to answer your question specifically.